# Can I obtain the last session time of all Jira users using the REST API?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

Can I use the REST API to filter out users who have not signed in during the last three months?

(I have admin access if that is needed).

Answer (score 0):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I know it's not available out of the box. You would probably need to implement a [REST plugin module](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/atlassian-platform-common-components/rest-api-development/rest-plugin-module) which would get this data from database (or find an existing plugin that does this - I haven't).

There's a page on Atlassian's Confluence that gives you SQLs to get the last login timestamp for a user (and it seems quite up-to-date): https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/Retrieve+last+login+dates+for+users+from+the+database

Please note that you would have to think about security when developing such a plugin. I have not really considered this, but there might be reasons to include permission restrictions for such a REST resource.

**EDIT**: I might have found an API (not REST) that exposes login information without the need to query the database (untested): https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/jira/reference/com/atlassian/jira/bc/security/login/LoginInfo.html

Comment: I am using JIRA on demand so there's access to DB and so I cannot use REST plugin module right?
Can I use the API you mentioned for JIRA on cloud?

Comment: Unfortunatelly with Cloud addons you are limited to JIRA Rest API and Webhooks and AFAIK neither provides this information.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the JIRA REST API doesn't provide this resource. The latest supported methods can be found on the [JIRA REST API Reference Page](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/).

These methods can be tested on your current installation using the [JIRA REST API Browser](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/developer-tools/using-the-rest-api-browser).

The links above contain all of the info you need on the REST API. If you're still interested in using REST, you can always create your own method for retrieving the user list.

Of course, you could use other methods, like SQL, for example. There are a number of plugins available [here](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?application=jira&category=&cost=&hosting=&marketingLabel=&q=sql).

Comment: I use JIRA on demand so there is no DB access, Are there any plugins to generate the reports for JIRA on demand?

Thank You

Comment: I looked through the documentation and marketplace and I don't see any straightforward way to implement a feature like this. At least with an On Demand account. Sorry.